# How do you subscribe array of FormData object in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Service class:

```
sendFiles(files: File[]): Observable<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
    formData.append("file", files[i]);
  } 
  return this.httpClient.post(this.url, formData);
}
```

The Component class:

```
uploadFile() {
  this.service.sendFiles(this.files).subscribe(
   response => { 
    this.files= response;
    console.log("Files: " + JSON.stringify(this.files));
  });
}
```

The above subscribe is only for one file.

How to do a POST and subscribe to each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I will attempt an answer regardless.

The observable that you subscribe to maps to a single request. If you make one POST request with your data, you will receive one response. It's up to your backend to decide what response to send back. If the response only contains one file, then your backend might not be returning what you expected.

If you don't care about making multiple requests, you can try a forkJoin or merge.

```
sendFile(file: File) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  return this.httpClient.post(this.url, formData)
    .map(response => JSON.stringify(response));
}

const requests = this.files.map(file => this.service.sendFile(file));

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(responses => {
  // An array of responses.
});

merge(...requests).subscribe(file => {
  // A single response.
});
```

The forkJoin will individually send each request, wait until each response has returned, then emit an array of each response.

The merge will individually send each request, and emit a response when it receives it.

I don't believe you need to call subscribe multiple times, but tell me if I'm wrong.